# An interesting application of little Picard theorem in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

If $f,g$ are entire functions, $p,q$ are polynomials in the complex plane satisfying $\exp(f)+p=\exp(g)+q, f(0)=g(0)$ prove that $f=g$ and $p=q$?

Here. My approach is very much messy and calculative. I am lost. How to proceed with this one?

I was trying in the way that if $q\ne p,$ then the polynomial $q-p$ is of a finite degree and therefore I calculate the derivative for $\exp(f)-\exp(g),$ but this seems a bad approach and I also can't express my solution here due to the very much intuition and vague calculation.
I expect a neat and crucial approach can anyone help.

Comment: Some clarification : polynomials p, q are considered to have finite degree,  before hand.  It is not something to imply....

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is *not* the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please show your approach, even if you find it “messy.”

Comment: actually mine is just calculate the derivative at 0 and follow the pattern this should give contradiction..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got one solution. We have to use little Picard theorem see $e^f-e^g=q-p$ ,now $e^f-e^g=e^g(e^{f-g}-1).$ Now see that if $f-g$ is not identically zero, then as it is entire non constant (as $f(0)=g(0)$ given), by little Picard theorem the range of $(f-g)(z)$ omits at most one point so..if $f(z)-g(z)$ can take $2n\pi i$ for infinitely many $n$..so $e^(f-g)-1$ is zero for infinitely many $z$ ..so in the RHS $q-p$ has infinitely many roots and, as they are polynomial, so $q-p=0$ ,so $q=p$ identically so this implies $g-f\in\{2n\pi:n\in\Bbb Z\}$ and by continuity $g-f$ is constant and as $g(0)=f(0)$ so $g=f$ identically on $C$..

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Nice proof! Now learn Mathjax so that more users can benefit from your answer.